# Copy SQL result into another table

Tags: entity-framework, t-sql

I need some help. I'm trying to copy a tsql query result into another table. I was able to do it with the below tsql but I need to put some sort of check method to not copy a record if it already exist in the "PageControls" table.

```
INSERT INTO PageControls (UserId, PageId)
SELECT t1.UserId, t2.PageId FROM
aspnet_users t1, Pages t2
```

How can I accomplish this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to populate the `pagecontrols` table with a `cartesian product` of users and pages.  Assuming that's your goal, then you can add `not exists` to your query to exclude those already in the `pagecontrols` table:

```
INSERT INTO PageControls (UserId, PageId)
SELECT t1.UserId, t2.PageId 
FROM aspnet_users t1, Pages t2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM PageControls p
    WHERE p.userid = t1.userid and p.pageid = t2.pageid
)
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/aeea9/1)

Comment: Thank you for the quick response..Work great!!